# How many reference images are needed for head modeling?

Tags: modeling

I'm a newbie, I noticed when you do head modeling, you need two picture, one for the face, and another for the side of the face.

What if I want to create a 3d model of someone and I don't have a picture of the side of his face, or maybe not a symmetrical picture, I mean what if he's smiling but the side picture he's not smiling.

Can you create a head model of someone using only one picture? How?

For instance, [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6p_e9ThK3U) and many other, use two images.

And finally, say you want to practice by modeling the faces of celebrities or whatever, is there a website that would provide you with two pictures, one for the face and another for the side of the face?

Comment: You could use a movie trailer(or the full length movie) with the actor you'd like to build a model of and take screen captures at some point when the actor is turning his or her head.

Comment: @MarcClintDion true good solution, so you always need 2 pictures? never 1?

Comment: You could do a google image search for 'mugshot' this will find many reference images.

Comment: Fisher, how are you supposed to know what's there if you don't have a picture to show what's there.  If you want to model the side of a house then you require a picture that shows you what's there or you have to guess.

Comment: @MarcClintDion what if all i care about is the face? no rotation

Comment: You can use only 1 image; You can also use no images. It won't be as accurate, but nothing prevents you. Also, I think you're taking the wrong approach here - it's better and easier to sculpt rather than model a face.